# Pull up a few photos(Shawn Mendes)

Tags: word-usage

What does "pull up a few"want her? I looked it up and it was about "getting information" ,so is that what Shawn meant here:

So can it be: You want information related to this,so just pull it up. (Does it mean : just look it up)

https://youtu.be/99t4EBwIAt8

It's said at around:2:35 min

Answer (score 2):

Here's the full transcript of what the says:

> "Did Shawn Mendes have braces?" I had braces for four and a half years. There's lots and lots and lots of photo evidence. I'm sure you can **pull up a few**.

It's quite obvious that by "**pull up a few**" he means "**you can easily find a few photos on the Internet where he wears braces which can serve as evidence that he used to wear braces in the past**." I think this is just a variation of the more commonly used expression [**to pull something off the Web**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pull-off) which basically means *to quickly find something online and download it*. Here's a simple example sentence:

> You can **pull the files you need off the Internet**.

Comment: I looked up online and I found that it means "to get information from the web". Like to search something online.

Comment: Well, you got it.

Comment: here's a link to that:https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+up. Is it okay? And I guess this is what he meant.

Comment: So what I  thought ,is it right?

Comment: Yes, you were on the right track.